# launch AddHostedService services in parallel

Tags: c#, .net-core, parallel-processing, .net-core-3.1, ihostedservice

In an .NET Core 3.1 (Console) application, is there a way to launch services, added by `AddHostedService` in parallel?

Actually the two services I add seem to be launched in synchronous mode (one after other)
My code is the following:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, confBuilder) =>
    {
        confBuilder
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        if (args.Contains(Args.Contoso))
        {
            services.AddHostedService(provider =>
                new ContosoService(
                    provider.GetService<ILogger<ContosoService>>(),
                    provider.GetService<IContosoRepository>(),
                    mode));
        }

        // if there also Alonso in the list, make them run in parallel !
        if (args.Contains(Args.Alonso))
        {
            services.AddHostedService(provider =>
                new AlonsoService(
                    provider.GetService<ILogger<AlonsoService>>(),
                    provider.GetService<IAlonsoRepository>(),
                    mode));
        }
    });
```

knowing that both services are `IHostedService`

```
public class AlonsoService : IHostedService {...}
public class ContosoService : IHostedService {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Actually the two services I add seem to be launched in synchronous mode (one after other)

By design the framework awaits the start of each hosted service one at a time in the order they were added to the service collection

[Source Code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostedServiceExecutor.cs,36)

```
internal class HostedServiceExecutor
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IHostedService> _services;
    private readonly ILogger<HostedServiceExecutor> _logger;

    public HostedServiceExecutor(ILogger<HostedServiceExecutor> logger, IEnumerable<IHostedService> services)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _services = services;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return ExecuteAsync(service => service.StartAsync(token));
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return ExecuteAsync(service => service.StopAsync(token), throwOnFirstFailure: false);
    }

    private async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<IHostedService, Task> callback, bool throwOnFirstFailure = true)
    {
        List<Exception>? exceptions = null;

        foreach (var service in _services)
        {
            try
            {
                await callback(service);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (throwOnFirstFailure)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                if (exceptions == null)
                {
                    exceptions = new List<Exception>();
                }

                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        }

        // Throw an aggregate exception if there were any exceptions
        if (exceptions != null)
        {
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
    }
}
```

note the awaited callback in the loop

Comment: so, it seems there is no way to launch them in parallel...?

Comment: @Serge not based on their current source code I found.

Comment: @Serge Any particular reason they need to be done in parallel?

Comment: just I have some long processes that addresses different data sources, so, are completely independent, why do not do it in parallel

Comment: @Serge you can, if you want to. In fact, the services themselves already run in parallel. The only thing called sequentially is `Start`, which is an `async` method. If the services run long processes, these are *already* executed in parallel

Comment: Any tutorial that I can follow in order to implement calling a web service with`Parallel.ForEachAsync` in an `IHostedService`? @PanagiotisKanavos @Nkosi